# How to embed (old) Tweets into a Presentation?

Tags: powerpoint, reveal.js, presentation, beamer

In a presentation, I would like to create a Twitter Timeline with a few selected tweets. In the best case it should look as natural as if someone went to Twitter on his own computer or saw it on his smartphone.

I am using LateX Beamer for the rest of the slides, but I am flexible if it is another software that allows to export a PDF/Image that I could include in LateX.

(There are a lot of tools on how to integrate live Tweets in PowerPoint / Keynote , but I want to do it for historical tweets and will be offline during the presentation.)

I was trying the following: 
- Simply take screenshots of the tweet and arrange them within LateX or PowerPoint. Looks ok but not super nice, and quite cumbersome to do.

- Since it is possible to extract an html of a tweet to embed on a homepage, I thought of doing this for the presentation. Unfortunately, I don't know much of html / reveal.js presentations.

Has anybody found a good solution for a similar problem?

EDIT:

I started reveal.js and found the following plugin: https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js-plugins/tree/master/embed-tweet

I was then trying to apply it and followed the intros to reveal.js and also saved the source code of the plugin into my plugin folder for reveal.js. However, it does not work (=Returning a blank page in the html). Can anybody point me to my error? (I am completely new to reveal.js / html so sorry if it is basic?)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reveal.js 3 Slide Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reveal.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme/default.css" id="theme"> 
    <!--Add support for earlier versions of Internet Explorer -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="lib/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Wrap the entire slide show in a div using the "reveal" class. -->
    <div class="reveal">
        <!-- Wrap all slides in a single "slides" class -->
        <div class="slides">

            <!-- ALL SLIDES GO HERE -->
            <!-- Each section element contains an individual slide -->
            <section>
                <div class="tweet" data-src="https://twitter.com/marcfbellemare/status/972558957645631488"></div>
            </section>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/js/head.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/reveal.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        // Required, even if empty.
        Reveal.initialize({
            // ...
            dependencies: [
                // ... 
                { src: 'plugin/embed-tweet/embed-tweet.js' },
                // ... 
            ]
        });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```